# Do I have to let the potential dwellers in?

Tags: fallout-shelter

So I have a Radio room and around two wandering dwellers show up a day. Initially I was just happy to have anyone but having children does seem to increase the population faster and with better ... or more determinable stats at the least.

I still like the random strangers showing up for a chance of something new but is there any way to tell them No and get them to go away when I don't want them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you can just leave them there, or in my case, you can just tell them to explore the wilderness without gear. **TO THEIR DEATH!**

Comment: Haha, I suppose that would indeed be a way to reject them!

Comment: I'm at 200 Dwellers, and this is indeed what it has come to.  Kind of frustrating to keep having to pull in people just to send them out to the wastes!